# React native bundle release there's no asset

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I'm creating a bundle release in react native android. I create an apk using "**assembleRelease**" I tested the assets are there but when I try to bundle in "**bundleRelease**" there's no asset.

The image show that my assets directory.

[image]

This is my **index.android.bundle**. The BGAppPros is automatically generated.

[image]

In my android/app/build.gradle

code looks like this.  I have a feeling this is the culprit " resourcesDirRelease "

In short I want an offline assets. but the bundle release is ibcompiled correctly.

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: 'index.js',
    bundleInRelease        : true,
     resourcesDirRelease   : 'src/release/res',
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem you need also check you'r script

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

make sure its the right path when you calling the

```
 resourcesDirRelease   : 'src/release/res',
```